# PHP force download can't open files after download

Tags: php, force-download

I am trying to implement the PHP force download and the used the code below

```
$length = sprintf("%u", filesize($path));
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . $length);
set_time_limit(0);
readfile($path);
exit;
```

The file is downloaded successfully with full size(i opened file in notepad++ and there is no php errors or warnings) but i can't open the file. The strange thing is i can download and open pdf files with out any problem. But files with formats like docx, png, jpg are courrepted

Comment: What are those backticks for?

Comment: It is somehow added when i put question here.It is not exist in the real code

Comment: I have answered similar question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23192683/php-force-download-downloading-corrupted-file/23193618#23193618

Comment: It helped me :) @Seti

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your content-length header temporarily, it may be wrong and causing the files to be incompletely downloaded (perhaps by a single byte). Also try setting your expiry time higher than 0; i've seen bugs in IE caused by this because the browser is deleting the file from the cache before the external program has time to load it.

Comment: Thanks SpliFF, this worked perfectly for me. I have the same issue accept the Content-Type: is set to a correct content type (application/pdf).

Answer (score 0):

use this for force download

```
header("Cache-Control:  maxage=1");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-length: ".filesize($path));
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($path)."\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You should use proper content-type

Here is list of content types: 
http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$file = "xyz.html"
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
readfile($file);
```

Comment: there was no error showed when I opened the file in Notepad++. And I compared the original file with the downloaded file. The difference which I could found  was the original file have some unicode characters and the downloaded file is not showing it(it is showing some letters like "EFR TRS" instead).

Answer (score 0):

```
    $file=FCPATH."downloaded/1462026746_IMG_2015.JPG"; //file location 
        if(file_exists($file)) {

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
        }
        else {
            die('The provided file path is not valid.');
        }
```

Comment: This will work fine. Please refresh browser download window. until download finished, please wait.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ob_get_clean();` before headers and 
`ob_clean(); flush();` before `readfile();`

I had the same problem and this solved it for me.